# tomee 8 change jaxrs provider

Tags: java, jackson, jax-rs, apache-tomee

we wanna to change jax rs provider on tomee 8. the default provider is johnzon and we want to change it to jackson fasterxml. this change worked in tomee 7.

1. we change open-ejb file and it's not working.

   cxf.jaxrs.providers = com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider
2. we change system.properties file on tomee/conf but it not worked for me.

   openejb.cxf.jax-rs.providers = com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider

Comment: Explain « not working » in detail.

Comment: provider didn't change and johnzon convert request to dto.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not enough only to mention fasterxml it should even ship with the webapplication.

You should provide the fasterxml lib inside your deployment

/opt/tomee/apache-tomee-plus-8.0.12/webapps//WEB-INF/lib

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
openejb.jaxrs.jsonProviders = com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider
```

in system.properties to make it work (and have the jackson-jaxrs-json-provider jars in your lib folder).

Comment: Does not work bro!